# Missing option "Run on Server" in Eclipse STS

Tags: eclipse, spring

I am new to Spring and I wanted to learn how to develop REST APIs using Spring so I have followed this tutorial:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

I am using STS and the problem is that when I try to run it, I dont have a "Run on Server" option. Why ? Sorry for the noob question

Regards

Comment: you probably need to define a server first

Comment: Did you read this guide? this is described **Build an executable JAR**, so run this JAR!

Comment: Yes I know but wanted it to run on a server

Comment: And you have converted your app to WAR?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Managed to make it show that option:

[image: Go to Project Properties]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Good job :) But why you need run on server?

Comment: How can I make http calls otherwise?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that 'Dynamic Web Module' is selected in the Project Facets of Project Properties.

Steps to follow:

1. Right click in the project and select properties.
2. Click on the Project Facets.
3. Check the Dynamic web module.

Answer (score 0):

**Install Eclipse Web Development Tools into your STS in Marketplace.**

Answer (score -1):

1.Go TO Help In STS AND CLick Eclipse MarketPlace Then
2.Click Eclipse WebModule And Install That Software Then
3.Clean Install And Try Update You Will Get Run As Server Option Will Apperar.

Comment: 1.Go TO Help In STS AND CLick Eclipse MarketPlace Then
2.Click Eclipse  Web Developer Tools  And Install That Software Then 
3.Clean Install And Try Update You Will Get Run As Server Option Will Apperar.